# Is it possible to get the localized display name of a SharePoint column via MS Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a SharePoint Online Modern Team site of which the default language is set to Dutch. When I use the Microsoft Graph Explorer to retrieve a document library and related columns all display values are in the English language. Is it possible to get the localized values via MS Graph?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Gijs Stoeldraaijers

Comment: If not already doing so, can you add a header for "Accept-Language" and specify the culture that is expected?  If that doesn't work let us know and can follow up with the respective PM.
[Accept-Language http header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language)

Comment: @brian-t-jackett-msft: Adding the HeaderOption with Accept-Language does not seem to work? See also my question here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Header option does not work

Sadly it's not possible to get the localized column names using the `new HeaderOption("Accept-Language", "nl-NL")`
[code as described here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/efc7a4c1d1fc195eb81c722167e2971f4c27d8a5/docs/headers.md).

#### Not yet implemented...

According to [this question and answer](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/926) this feature is not yet (*2021 March*) implemented.

So the only option for now is to use [CSOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard) to get this information.

#### More references

- https://answers.microsoft.com/threadauth/c46d5dae-84d3-4db0-ba50-c30bd5987c88
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/how-to-get-the-local-translated-column-name-from-a-sharepoint/m-p/2201747/thread-id/10127/highlight/true

#### User-Voice

I did create a User-Voice request here
https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42889503-return-localized-column-names-from-a-sharepoint-li to enable localized column names using the Microsoft Graph.